# Simple Symmetric Random Walk on the Integer Values

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk

I want to prove that the simple symmetric random walk on the integer values with start in 0 is visiting the state N with probability 1/N+1 before visiting the negative numbers.

I already tried to do it by induction but it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The idea is to notice your random walk $(X_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is a martingale and apply the [Optional Stopping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem), which implies that is $n$ is the time when either $-1$ is hit or when $N>0$ is hit, then
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_n] = \mathbb{E}[X_0] = \mathbb{E}[0] = 0.
$$
Now note that $X_n \in \{-1,N\}$ by definition, so if $p$ is the probability $X_n = -1$ then 
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_n] = p(-1) + (1-p)N = N -p(N+1),
$$
so you get 
$$
0 = N -p(N+1).
$$
Can you solve for $p$ and complete the problem?